# NodeJs TypeScript namespaces between files

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using typescript 2.4.2 with node v6.11.2.

I'm coming from the .net world and try to understand how can I arrange my code in Node with typescript.

I define namespaces in my code in this way :

hirarchy :

```
src
index.ts
-----DataModel
----------------Customer.ts
----------------Employee.ts
```

customer class :

```
Customer.ts :
export namespace DataModel {
    export class Customer {
    }
}
```

employee class :

```
Employee.ts 
export namespace DataModel {
    export class Employee {
    }
}
```

What is the way to use classes from DataModel namespace in other files?

index.ts
something like this :

```
//import row .
DataModels.Employee 
DataModels.Customer
```

Comment: There's no need to use namespaces, it won't get you want you're looking for. Each file is a module. What you can do is have a `DataModel/index.ts` file where you re-import everything in the directory

Answer (score 0):

> I'm coming from the .net world and try to understand how can I arrange my code in Node with typescript.

In JavaScript / TypeScript the modules replace the namespaces. And the module names are the file paths.

You could use the following hierarchy:

```
src/
|_ index.ts
|_ DataModel/
   |_ Customer.ts
   |_ Employee.ts
```

In `DataModel/Customer.ts`:

```
export default class Customer {
}
```

In `DataModel/Employee.ts`:

```
export default class Employee {
}
```

Then, in `index.ts`:

```
import Customer from "./DataModel/Customer"
import Employee from "./DataModel/Employee"
```